# If I have apply(i: Int), how can I have map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a class `E` with a number of elements.  I would like E to implement `Iterable` or a similar Collections interface.  I can retrieve any arbitrary element.

In other words: I have a class which supports `apply(n: Int)`, to give element n.  I would like to support map and similar methods.  How can I do this?

**UPDATE:** In other words, I'd like it to have the Collections interface

Comment: I doubt there is a general answer. What methods do you want to support? (`map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter`?) What does your class represent, what should these methods do?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote! First, I believe it is possible: see update.  More importantly, who ever heard of downvoting because there is no way to do it?

Comment: If you want to "support" `map`, you... define a `map` method? If you want to implement the methods of some particular trait (e.g. `Traversable` or `Seq`), extend that trait (there is no "Collections interface" though, as far as I know). (You're not being downvoted because there's no way to do it, but because your question is very unclear and it's not clear you've tried even the most basic, obvious things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with `apply` alone since all non-Stream collections need a size, but if you can implement `apply` and `length` you can then just inherit from `IndexedSeq` and you will have most of the general collection methods implemented for you.

For instance, here's how you could do it with a collection that wrapps an array:

```
class ArrayCollection[+E]( items : Array[E] ) extends IndexedSeq {

  override def apply(n : Int) : E = items(n)

  override def length : Int = items.length

}
```